# Prove that $A^{c}\subseteq B\cap C^{c}$ iff $(A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C^{c}) = U$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, set-theory, computer-science

Let $A$ and $B$ be subsets of the universal set $U$. Prove that
$$A^{c}\subseteq B\cap C^{c} \Longleftrightarrow (A\cup B)\cap(A\cup C^{c}) = U$$

We haven't learned any laws surrounding subsets in proofs, I feel like law of subtraction may be a good place to start but I can't figure out where to go

Comment: This **type** of problem becomes **ridiculously easy**, if you use a [truth table](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454505/proof-performed-in-inclusion-of-sets/4454555#4454555).